# Accessing 2D NSMutableArray Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I'm currently trying to create and access data in a 2D NSMutableArray. I understood that I have to nest arrays into an array. The thing is I have trouble accessing the different 1D arrays.

Here is the code to initialize the 2D array, all arrays being NSMuttableArray :

```
if(simSections == nil  || [simSections count] == 0) {
    simSections = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i = 0; i < 8 ; i++) {
        simData[i] = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [simSections addObject:simData[i]];
    }
}
```

And now I'm trying to add on object in the first space of the first array :

```
[[simSections objectAtIndex:0] addObject:[NSString stringWithString:@"Test"]];
```

I'm getting this error, but I don't understand why the *simSections* array would be empty since I added the *simData* arrays.

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'

Do you have any idea ? I would very much enjoy your help,

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check your simSections array. It seems that it is empty

Comment: But if I do the following "[simSections addObject:simData[i]];" wouldn't it be non-empty ?

Comment: Check in debugger, that before this call your array contains all the objects

Answer (score 0):

Your code for filling `simSections` seems right to me. I suspect, then, that the problem is that that code has not actually been called for the object that's then doing `[simSections objectAtIndex:0]`.

Add logging to both pieces of code. Log `self` and `simSections` to make sure they are the same objects you expect them to be. You may wish to log with the "%p" format specifier rather than "%@" because you're really just interested in their pointer value.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately the problem doesn't seem to lie here since I got the following when logging the simSections pointer in the both methods : 2012-06-06 10:22:28.158 GlassCockpit[8584:707] arrayAlloc: 0x7c71810
2012-06-06 10:22:38.807 GlassCockpit[8584:707] udp: 0x7c71810

Comment: OK. Out of curiosity, what is `simData` in your snippet? A local, an ivar, ...? Show its declaration, too. Also show the declaration of `simSections`. And by the way, is this using ARC?

Comment: simData in an instance variable, declared as the following:    "NSMutableArray *simData [100];". For simSections which is also an ivar : "NSMutableArray *simSections;". The project is not using ARC.

Comment: I'm stumped. You probably need to add more context to your question. Show the methods in which those code snippets appear and explain when they're called. Frankly, you may need to show all the code which touches `simSections` and `simData`. By the way, why are you using the `simData` array? Seems redundant with `simSections`.

Comment: I actually quitted this and I'll do something else which will work as well, much more easily using multiple 1D Arrays. As you mentioned, I don't really need having the simData arrays. Thanks for your help.